# Extending class datatype from within another class

Tags: c#

First I apologize if this has been asked before but I have no idea what to search on and my searches came up empty.

I'm attempting to remove some nuget packages from my projects, specifically the Google APIs.  The only thing I need the packages for in the other projects right now are the return data classes.  What I want to do is expose these classes to the processing class I created.

I have a google processing class which uses the nuget Google.Apis.Directory.directory_v1 package.

Within that nuget package there's a definition of User which is of type iDirectResponseSchema and is defined like this (Google's code):

```
public class User : IDirectResponseSchema
{
    public User();

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Kind of resource this is.
    [JsonProperty("kind")]
    public virtual string Kind { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("languages")]
    public virtual object Languages { get; set; }
...... additional properties
}
```

So consider my class to be

```
public class ProcessGoogle 
{
     public User GetOneUser(string email)
     {
       User loadUser; // Google's data class
       loadUser = service.Users.Get(email);
       return loadUser;
     }
}
```

What I call that class from my other projects it still returns data of type:
  Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.User which I do expect.  But is it possible to make that User class accessible from within my class so I don't need to include the Google APIS in my other projects or am I stuck with doing that?

I tried creating a class inheritance and it kind of works but I'd need to re-work a lot of code.  I was hoping that there would be an easier way...

Comment: You can just create a new class called `User` with the properties that exist in the same class from the nuget package. At least it sounds like you just need the properties and not any additional behavior that might be in that class. You can specify the namespace that class resides in as `Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1` to avoid dealing with namespace issues throughout the rest of your code, thought it might be a little misleading so I'd make sure to comment intent.

Comment: I also considered that but if google changes the data properties it will require me to be aware that it changed (it's taken care of now) and update that class by hand....

Comment: If the other projects only care about certain data provided by the nuget package, I would make the processing class return a new class that the projects need. That way nuget package changes only need to happen in your processing class, which can take the information from the nuget User object and transform/ignore to still create your custom object to be used by your other projects. Your processing class should insulate your other projects from API changes.

Comment: ... Hmm, I wasn't thinking about it that way... Thanks!